# Android layout problem, ImageView not appearing in desired place (between two other Views)

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to android development and I'm trying to make a screen (a layout) that resembles this: a spinner, and two text fields on top, a thumbnail (ImageView) just below on the left side, and a fragment container view below that I will use to show a different page. Right now I'm not looking for beautiful design, I just want to make android display it like this.

[image]

The problem is that, even though on the design tab of android studio the thumbnail is shown in the correct place, on runtime is completely wrong:

[image]

Here is the Component Tree and the layout's xml in case it's useful:

[image]

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_note"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".NoteActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.NoteKeeper.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.NoteKeeper.PopupOverlay" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<include
    android:id="@+id/include"
    layout="@layout/content_note" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fragmentContainerView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView2"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="367dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

EDIT:

In the end, I had to use constraint layout like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_note"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".NoteActivity">


    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarContentNoteLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.NoteKeeper.AppBarOverlay"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.NoteKeeper.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/content_note"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarContentNoteLayout" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#AC1A1A"
        android:backgroundTint="#C51111"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Added tint so that the fragment view would show the borders

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using layout_gravity in your xml code that works in some view groups like `FrameLayout` but it doesn't work in `ConstraintLayout`. And the second fact is you don't need to use nested ConstraontLayouts and one will handle All of your ui requirements. So for the first one that is `AppBar` you can use `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` and for content note, you can constraint it to bottom of the appBar as well. Like this: `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBar"` and also for the image thumbnail use this: `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/contentNote"` together with `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"` and for the last one as fragmentContainer you can use this `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"`.
This way all of them will be constrainted to each other and works well. And for any other constraints for them related to the parent layout, you can add their constraints as well.

Comment: Thanks, that pretty much worked, I only had to change the fragment view at the bottom to 

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"

and 

        android:layout_height="0dp"

so that it would fill the remaining space (from end of image, to the bottom of the UI). Thanks man!!! :D

Answer (score -1):

Your constraints are wrong in the `ImageView`.

Try getting rid of the following line

```xml
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

in your `ImageView` as this line of code is trying to pull the top of your image all the way to the top of the parent.

Lmk if that works. Otherwise, I can send you a complete layout code snippet instead.

Comment: Sorry that didn't work :/ . Still located pretty much in the same place.